# Android RecyclerView Grid center items horizontally and vertically without scolling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I want to display RecyclerView Grid items in the middle of the screen (Both horizontally and verically) and when the items expand, the view doesn't scroll, however it should resize the elements to fit the new available screen size. 
I hope this image tells what I want in a short message:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq3be.png)

my current code for the recycler is

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
         android:padding="16dp"
         android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

     </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and for the item view

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="54dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/appIcon"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appName"
            android:contentDescription="icon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="name"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/appName"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Any other options other than `RecyclerView` (as GridLayout or FlexLayout) are welcomed

Comment: What happens if you have more than 32 items? Can the number of items change after loading? What if one user has a shorter phone (different aspect ratio)?

Comment: The items should be squeezed/adapted to the screen size

Comment: And no, the number of items won't change after loading (it will be grabbed from the start from the database)

Comment: Do you intend for the number of columns to change? (two of your examples have 3 columns, and one has 4 columns). The only way I can imagine this working is to manually override the row height & column count in your Kotlin code. Column count is easy to update; row height is harder, but maybe you can control width + aspect ratio if your item layout uses ConstraintLayout. You'd also need to know whether you're limited by horizontal or vertical space (which may differ phone to phone).

Answer (score 0):

Add a mother view for the recyclerview, and give us a gravity/layout-gravity to center, like that:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tried that already, but once the items are so many, scrollbars will appear which I don't want

Comment: so add the following to your xml: android:scrollbars="none".

Answer (score 0):

Place your RecyclerView inside a RelativeLayout and change the code into this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:padding="16dp"
android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/></RelativeLayout>
```

And give some margin to your item view's root RelativeLayout.

Comment: Tried that already, but once the items are so many, scrollbars will appear which I don't want